# discovery.seed_hosts in elasticsearch AWS EC2 with ELB

Tags: elasticsearch, amazon-ec2, elastic-stack, amazon-elb, elk

I have EC2 instances under an ELB. Whenever a new instance is started an ip address is assigned dynamically.

I have added the ELB DNS name, but it is referring the ip addresses from Network Interfaces tagged to the ELB. But I need to add the ec2 instance ip address.

So how do I add the new ip address in discovery.seed_hosts in elasticsearch without manual intervention?

Note:- I am looking for a way other than ec2 discovery plugin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used aws cli command to fetch the IP's from AWS ELB. Added the following script to my .sh file

```
export ELASTIC_INSTANCE_IPS=$(aws ec2 describe-instances --filters file://filters.json --query "Reservations[*].Instances[*].PrivateIpAddress" --region ${aws_region} --output text | paste -sd,)

tee -a elasticsearch.yml << END

discovery.seed_hosts: [$ELASTIC_INSTANCE_IPS]
```